# DelegateCommand Not Firing in Xamarin using Prism

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, prism

I am creating a Login and Register page and making navigation between the two page. LoginPage is able to navigate to RegisterPage but in RegisterPage both the delegate command is not even firing.

Below is the code for RegisterPageViewModel:

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Navigation;
using Dialog.Interfaces;
using Prism.Services;

namespace Dialog.ViewModels
{
    public class RegisterPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private INavigationService _navigationservice;
        private IRegistrationService _registartionService;
        private IPageDialogService _pageDialogService;
        private string _email;
        private string _password;
        private string _confirmpassword;

        public DelegateCommand NavigateToLoginCommand { get; private set; }
        public DelegateCommand RegisterCommand { get; private set; }


        public string Email
        {
            get
            {
                return _email;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _email, value);
            }
        }
        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return _password;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _password, value);
            }
        }
        public string ConfirmPassword
        {
            get
            {
                return _confirmpassword;
            }
            set
            {
                SetProperty(ref _confirmpassword, value);
            }
        }


        public RegisterPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, IRegistrationService registrationService, IPageDialogService pageDialogService) : base(navigationService)
        {
            _navigationservice = navigationService;
            _registartionService = registrationService;
            _pageDialogService = pageDialogService;

            NavigateToLoginCommand = new DelegateCommand(NavigateToLoginPage);
            RegisterCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnRegisterCommandExecuted, RegisterCommandCanExecute)
                .ObservesProperty(() => Email)
                .ObservesProperty(() => Password)
                .ObservesProperty(() => ConfirmPassword);
        }

        private bool RegisterCommandCanExecute()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Email) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ConfirmPassword) && IsNotBusy;
        }

        private void OnRegisterCommandExecuted()
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            _registartionService.CreateUser("xxx", "xxxx", "xxx");
            IsBusy = false;
        }

        private void NavigateToLoginPage()
        {
            _navigationservice.GoBackAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

RegisterCommandCanExecute() is working fine and enables the Register button. But Commands are not getting fired.

RegisterPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Dialog.Views.RegisterPage" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Entry">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,10" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email Address" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding ConfirmPassword}" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Confirm Password" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Register" Command="{Binding RegisterCommand}" />
            <Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding NavigateToLoginCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The code is same for LoginPageViewModel and its working fine. I have registered the Page for Navigation in App.xaml.cs. 
Below is the Code for App.xaml.cs

```
using Prism;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Dialog.ViewModels;
using Dialog.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using Dialog.Interfaces;
using Dialog.Services;
using Prism.Unity;

[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace Dialog
{
    public partial class App: PrismApplication
    {
        /* 
         * The Xamarin Forms XAML Previewer in Visual Studio uses System.Activator.CreateInstance.
         * This imposes a limitation in which the App class must have a default constructor. 
         * App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) cannot be handled by the Activator.
         */
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public static new App Current
        {
            get { return Application.Current as App; }
        }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if (App.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("isLoggedIn"))
                await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/RegisterPage");
            else
                await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/LoginPage");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<LoginPage, LoginPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<RegisterPage, RegisterPageViewModel>();
            containerRegistry.Register<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();
            containerRegistry.Register<IRegistrationService, RegistrationService>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say commands not getting fired. Do you mean if you place a break point inside nothing happens? You might want to try putting try/catches to see if maybe it is breaking.

Comment: debugger is also not getting hit.